# Recurring decimal rounding to second place

Tags: java, math

I have a division 4/3 which produces 1.33333333... I am storing the result in java double and I want to round this result to 1.34. How can this be done in Java ?

```
import java.text.*;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){


     DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
     decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
      String dd =decimalFormat.format(1.33333333);
      System.out.println(dd);
     }
}
```

Works with (Math.ceil(1.333333 * 100) / 100.0) but not with DecimalFormat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: Thanks but that does not work, I tried with all the rounding modes

Comment: Why would you want `1.34` and `1.33` is closer to the correct answer?

Comment: I want to convert it (1.33 or 1.34) to hours and minutes and it makes difference there of 1 minute

Comment: You can do `Math.ceil(x * 100) / 100.0` and this will turn 1.33333 into 1.34

Comment: If two decimal places is not enough, I suggest using more decimal places.

Comment: around how many for conversion to hr,mins & seconds?